# What is a right Spring Cache Configuration for Java Map and its values?

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot

I have next service that returns the whole map and a value by a key.

```
@Service
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "messages")
public class MessageService {

    private final MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageService(MessageRepository messageRepository) {
        this.messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }

    @Cacheable
    public Map<String, String> findMessages() {
        return messageRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Cacheable(key = "#key")
    public String getMessage(String key) {
        return messageRepository.findByKey(key);
    }
}
```

When `findMessages()` method will be invoked I want to save all the messages in cache. And when `getMessage(String key)` will be invoked it should return a value from the cache, but not from the repository. Is it possible to do it using Spring annotations? Currently it have separate cache entries for both of the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as supposed, when you *separate* the methods into different services (public facades).

Starting from [spring-caching example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-caching.git) (`/complete`), I moved `SimpleBookRepository` with small adjustments to a new class (supposed to be the "cached service"):

```
@Component
public class SimpleCache {

    @Cacheable("map")
    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        simulateSlowService();
        Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("foo", "bar");
        result.put("bar", "foo");
        return result;
    }

    // Don't do this at home
    private void simulateSlowService() {
        try {
            long time = 3000L;
            Thread.sleep(time);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Some small adjustments to match the question/example:

```
package hello;

public interface BookRepository {
    //originally it returned {@link hello.Book}
    String getByIsbn(String isbn);
}
```

...and introducing (as the cache facade/invoker  ... no sense in caching `getByIsbn()`!!):

```
@Component
public class SimpleBookRepository implements BookRepository {
    @Autowired
    private transient SimpleCache cache;

    @Override
    public String getByIsbn(String isbn) {
       return cache.getMap().get(isbn);
    }

}
```

With a slightly adjusted `AppRunner`:

```
//...
logger.info(".... Fetching books");
logger.info("foo --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("foo"));
logger.info("bar --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("bar"));
logger.info("foo --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("foo"));
logger.info("bar --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("bar"));
logger.info("foo --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("foo"));
logger.info("foo --> {}", bookRepository.getByIsbn("foo"));
//...
```

...we get the following output:

```
2017-06-30 15:54:52.584 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : .... Fetching books
2017-06-30 15:54:55.616 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : foo --> bar
2017-06-30 15:54:55.618 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : bar --> foo
2017-06-30 15:54:55.619 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : foo --> bar
2017-06-30 15:54:55.619 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : bar --> foo
2017-06-30 15:54:55.619 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : foo --> bar
2017-06-30 15:54:55.619 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.AppRunner : foo --> bar
2017-06-30 15:54:55.623 INFO 3984 --- [ main] hello.Application  : Started Application in 4.982 seconds (JVM running for 5.513)
```

;)

Comment: The solutions don't work. `getMessages()` method is invoked bypass the cache. Anyway, how should it work? When I invoke `getMessages()` outside `MessageService`, JDK proxy is involved. So, Spring refers to the cache and don't invoke real implementation. In case of `getMessage(String key)` method, I invoke it inside `MessageService`. Therefore, JDK proxy is not involved and Spring doesn't refer to the cache. Just in case, I'm using Spring Boot with default configuration.

Comment: I added @EnableCaching annotation to my main class and defined next configuration to my application yaml

  cache:
    cache-names: messages
    caffeine.spec: expireAfterAccess=3600s
Did I miss something?

Comment: i found (tested) a solution, @EugeneMironenko! ..will edit my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just do something like

```
public String getMessage(String key) {
    return findMessages().get(key)
}
```

I don't think you need to annotate getMessage with @Cacheable since you are accessing findMessages() which is already cached.

Ah @xerx593 bet me to it :)